# Muting/changing volume/EQ of tabs or elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, google-chrome-extension, io

For context about the procedure I am trying to figure out, see this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2muMCAaTL0

which demonstrates the use of this chrome/firefox?/opera extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ears-bass-boost-eq-any-au/nfdfiepdkbnoanddpianalelglmfooik

Disclaimer, I am not promoting the extension, nor do I think it is necessarily good practice to arbitrarily force tabs to sound a particular way, though I do see how useful the extension could be for some people.

I am curious how he did it, however, because it seems like **controlling the volume and EQ of DOM elements** isn't trivial, and I haven't been able to find any tutorials on how to do it. For example, is this approach viable for iframe elements? Wouldn't that potentially produce a cross-domain issue?

That being said, I am interested in volume controls/EQ not only for embedded iframes but also for locally hosted objects in my program. I would like to programatically control EQ, in the way that https://alemangui.github.io/pizzicato/ or tone.js can do but for modular sources, like a youtube video or a soundcloud stream, effectively allowing the user to "remix" a premade sound.

As far as I can tell, tone.js and pizzicato can only do this for an explicitly provided source sound, in the form of an mp3 or other.

Any direction would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As you can see in the source code it simply loads the audio URL inside its background page in a new AudioContext, applies the EQ, and plays it.

Comment: I didn't realize the sourcecode for the extension was public... where did you find it? And isn't it impossible to extract/manipulate such information from a cross-domain iframe/tab? Thanks!

Comment: Extensions are simply a bunch of js and css, you can inspect the code in devtools.

Comment: Yes I realize that now, thank you. However, the code is somewhat minified and I'm finding it really hard to understand at all what's going on. How did you figure it out?

Comment: Devtools has a `{}` button to prettify/reformat the code, but it's better to load the extension directory in a proper JavaScript IDE like VSCode/Atom etc.